# Vários erros como esse no console: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Olá, estou tendo vários erros como esse no console do navegador (conforme imagem). Todos esses scripts são do próprio Wordpress, nada ai foi eu que coloquei.

Já desabilitei todos os plugins, mas o problema persistiu. Estou usando a última versão do Wordpress 4.9.8. Antes estava dando erro no jquery, vi que o WP usava uma versão antiga, então atualizei e parou de aparecer o erro do jquey, mas desses outros ai persistem. [image: Imagem do console]

Comment: Cara sem ver os códigos fica bem difícil de se palpitar, porém, pela imagem está dando erros em plugins jQuery como de media, draggable, datepicker, etc... Provavelmente terá que atualizar os plugins também!

Comment: E qual o problema? Está afetando alguma funcionalidade da aplicação? É de se esperar que uma aplicação lotada de plugins que precisam de outros plugins e bibliotecas que nem se sabe da onde vem ou pra que que serve cause erros no console. Quanto mais coisa vai adicionando maior a chance de dar erros, as bibliotecas começam a interferir uma nas outras e causa erros

Comment: Todos os plugins estão atualizados. E sim, está afetando, o menu administrador não está funcionando corretamente, não aparece os icones por exemplo. Acho que algum desses plugins js está afetando todos os demais.

Comment: isso está parecendo que falta algum include de biblioteca